# How create object and and the new created object events by coding in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, events, object, visual-studio-2012

Hello Friends i hava a big problem with my new project,
How to create object and and the new created object events by coding in vb.net

this is my code i can create the object with array but i can't apply any event

```
    Dim C_R_ARRY(2) As TableLayoutPanel
    For x As Integer = 2 To 0 Step -1

        ' part 1
        Dim C_A_LABEL_1(2) As Label
        Dim C_A_LABEL_1_VALUE() As String = {"ADAM", "SOLY", "HESHAM"}
        C_A_LABEL_1(x) = New Label
        C_A_LABEL_1(x).Text = C_A_LABEL_1_VALUE(x)
        C_A_LABEL_1(x).Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        C_A_LABEL_1(x).TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        C_A_LABEL_1(x).Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill

        ' part 1
        Dim C_A_LABEL_2(2) As Label
        Dim C_A_LABEL_2_VALUE() As String = {"122", "231", "102"}
        C_A_LABEL_2(x) = New Label
        C_A_LABEL_2(x).Text = C_A_LABEL_2_VALUE(x) & " +"
        C_A_LABEL_2(x).Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        C_A_LABEL_2(x).TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        C_A_LABEL_2(x).Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill

        ' part 3
        Dim C_A_TEXT(2) As TextBox
        Dim C_A_TEXT_ID() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
        C_A_TEXT(x) = New TextBox
        C_A_TEXT(x).Width = 100
        C_A_TEXT(x).Name = "TEXT" & x

        ' part 0
        C_R_ARRY(x) = New TableLayoutPanel
        C_R_ARRY(x).AutoSize = True
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnCount = 6
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
        C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle())
        C_R_ARRY(x).Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top
        C_R_ARRY(x).Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        C_R_ARRY(x).Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        C_R_ARRY(x).RowCount = 1
        C_R_ARRY(x).RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle())
        C_R_ARRY(x).Size = New System.Drawing.Size(620, 100)
        C_R_ARRY(x).TabIndex = 0
        C_R_ARRY(x).Padding = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 5, 5, 10)



        C_R_ARRY(x).Controls.Add(C_A_LABEL_1(x), 0, 0)
        C_R_ARRY(x).Controls.Add(C_A_LABEL_2(x), 1, 0)
        C_R_ARRY(x).Controls.Add(C_A_TEXT(x), 2, 0)

        Panel3.Controls.Add(C_R_ARRY(x))

    Next

    Private Sub TEXT1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles = TEXT1.TextChanged
        ' not working
    End Sub
```

Thanks For Your Time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `Handles` part of your method declaration, and use [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/7taxzxka.aspx) to subscribe to the event dynamically:

```
AddHandler C_A_TEXT(x).TextChanged, AddressOf TEXT1_TextChanged
```

I'd also *strongly* advise you to use more conventional (less shouty) variable names. Additionally, your code will be more concise if you avoid fully-qualifying all the names. So this:

```
C_R_ARRY(x).ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 140.0!))
```

... might become:

```
panels(x).ColumnsStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 140.0F))
```

(I've used `F` instead of `!` as the `Single` suffix, just because it looks more natural to me as a C# programmer. I don't know which is more common in VB code.)

Comment: Thanks You Very Much Mr.Jon, i have been try it and worked :),